# Test partial object properties with Chai's Expect interface

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai

I have an object with many properties and want to check some of them. But one of the fields  is a random string so that cannot be checked for an exact match.

```
const expectedObject = {
  a: 'A',
  b: 123,
  c: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
  random: 'dsfgshdfsg'
}
```

Checking with `eql` doesn't work due to the random field.

```
expect(result).to.eql(expectedObject)
```

Is there a similar method where I can provide an object with only the fields I want to test?

The alternative is to delete the random field for the test, but this is a bit cumbersome.

```
const resultWithKnownFields = {...result}
delete resultWithKnownFields.random
const expectedObject = {
  a: 'A',
  b: 123,
  c: ['x', 'y', 'z']
}
expect(resultWithKnownFields).to.eql(expectedObject)
expect(result.random.length).to.equal(10)
```

Comment: Try `to.containSubset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.containSubset()` method of [chai-subset](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-subset/) plugin.
Partial matching can be performed on the fields in the object.

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiSubset = require('chai-subset');
chai.use(chaiSubset);

describe('69555042', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const expectedObject = {
      a: 'A',
      b: 123,
      c: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    };
    const result = {
      a: 'A',
      b: 123,
      c: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
      random: 'dsfgshdfsg',
    };
    expect(result).to.containSubset(expectedObject);
    expect(typeof result.random).to.equal('string');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option you can use without a plugin is to use spread syntax to produce a new object using the original object. That way any values you don't care about start as being equal anyway and are effectively ignored in the comparison.

```js
expect(result).to.eql({
  ...result,
  a: 'A',
  b: 123,
  c: ['x', 'y', 'z']
  // 'random' would have the same value as result
});
```

It does become a bit cumbersome if you want to test nested members because you have to spread each one.

```js
expect(result).to.eql({
  a: 'A',
  nestedObject: {
    ...result.nestedObject,
    nestedProperty: 'whatever'
  }
});
```